# Disable add to cart for cross category product purchases

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products

I have a unique requirement where If a product has been added to the shopping basket and it belongs to a specific category let's say category "K", add to cart buttons for all products that don't belong to category K should be disabled (on category pages). If on the other hand product in the cart belongs to any category other than category K, all products of category K should not show add to cart button.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is only a handful of products, I would think about adding a new attribute to do this. Attributes are just by hand and you can load them together with the quoteItems, so it is easy to check what status currently is. This logic can easily be implemented in an observer for `isSalable()` via `catalog_product_is_salable_after`.

If you need more different categories, you should think about something on the quote to save the different states and allows, by using `checkout_cart_product_add_after`, and then do the same by implementing a second observer on `catalog_product_is_salable_after`

Comment: Hi and welcome to Mageoverflow! Please don't post thank comments, but instead upvote. So the comments don't get littered but can easily be read with on topic stuff :)